# What metadata does RAW support that TIFF doesn't?

Tags: raw, metadata, tiff

RAW and JPEG both support recording of a lot about the shooting,ranging from the İSO to what lens was used at what coordinates.

When I convert CR2 RAW to 16 bit lossless TIFF, what will I lose?

(I own Photoshop CS6.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, first, the image will be demosaiced, white and black levels set, white balance adjusted, and a tone curve applied. With 16 bits to play with, most of this can be adjusted later without much problem — but it *is* lossy. The demosaicing is irreversible. None of this is metadata, but it is important to know. See more at [What is lost when RAW is exported to TIFF for editing?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24046/what-is-lost-when-raw-is-exported-to-tiff-for-editing) and [Does converting RAW files to TIFF lose image quality?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/49135/does-converting-raw-files-to-tiff-lose-image-quality/)

Second, there is information stored in something called "maker notes". This often holds things like focus point selected, face detection information, and other non-standard metadata. Sometimes this is even encrypted. Some programs will ignore this completely and so not copy it to your new file — in particular, Adobe tools like Photoshop and Lightroom [apparently drop makernotes](https://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/makernotes-metadata).

The best source of info I know for manufacturer-specific details is the [exiv2 metadata library documentation](http://exiv2.org/makernote.html).

Comment: Another good source would be [ExifTool's "Tags" site](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/index.html) - not as well organised (IMHO), but at least for Canon, the tags listed are far more extensive.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that, while exiftool won't write a lot of those proprietary tags, it *will* [copy them](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html#COPYING-EXAMPLES), either to another image file or an XMP sidecar file. This can be useful for workflows with intermediate files.

Comment: Programs may also change and add their own tags.